# Dictionary instantiate

Tags: c#, dictionary, type-conversion, new-operator, instantiation

```
Dictionary<string,object> dict = new Dictionary <string,object>();
```

Can I instantiate the "`dict`" with some other objects?

For instance:

```
dict = new Dictionary<string,bitmap>();
```

or:

```
dict = new Dictionary<string, Image>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because `Dictionary<string, object>` and `Dictionary<string, Bitmap>` are two different types.

Imagine what would happen in the following scenario:

```
Dictionary<string, Bitmap> bmpDict = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
Dictionary<string, object> dict = bmpDict;
dict.Add("someKey", 42);
```

The compiler would have to compile it, because the values in `dict` are typed to `object`, hence and `int` is a valid choice. However, this would clash with the instantiated dictionary that accepts only `Bitmap` values:

```
Bitmap someBmp = bmpDict["someKey"];
```

Obviously, the value should be a `Bitmap` as per the declared and instantiated type of `bmpDict`, but as we've seen above, something that is not a `Bitmap` was added via the `dict` variable. As you can see, type-safety would be broken.

Therefore, `Dictionary<string, object>` and `Dictionary<string, Bitmap>` cannot be assigned to each other.

Comment: @GennadyVanin--ГеннадийВанин: 1) `Bitmap someBmp = bmpDict["someKey"];` would be compileable, as the indexer of `bmpDict` returns `Bitmap` values. 2) Type-safety is not broken by `object o = new Image();`; it's not claimed anywhere that `o` is a `Image`. In contrast, `bmpDict` claims that all of its values are `Bitmap`, whereas `dict` allows the addition of non-`Bitmap` values.

Comment: Am still, see my[ Update](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14374638/200449),  not quite sure

Comment: what about object a =new Image(); a is assigned a image and a is passed to the dictionary values and the image in the dictionary how can it be displayed in a data grid column

Comment: @whathaveItried: Displaying an image in a data grid column is completely unrelated to storing an image in a dictionary, or the question at hand. If you need any advice on how to display images in a data grid column, please open a separate question.

Comment: storing an image in the dictionary.The dictionary serves as a Itemsource to the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

If to answer direct question.
It is impossible to istantiate as

```
Dictionary<string, object> dick; 
dick = new Dictionary<string, Image>();
```

because **dick** is declared as dictionary type that can hold objects of any type which is in contradiction with dictionary that can hold the values of only Image type objects.

Though, of course, you can fill **dick** with values of any type.

**Update:**
I am still in doubt about [explanation by O. R. Mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14374605/200449) and how to correctly interpret it.

Such logic doesn't explain much.

1)

`Bitmap someBmp = bmpDict["someKey"];`

should have worked as

`object someBmp = bmpDict["someKey"];`

2)
By this logic, it would have been impossible to instantiate as

```
object obj = new Image();
obj = new BitmapImage();
```

but it is possible.

IMO, the gist here is that the dictionary of type

- `Dictionary <string, Image>()`

can contain values only of the same (or compatible sub-) type while dictionary of type

- `Dictionary<string, object>`

of different?

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "should have worked as"? Can you rephrase that, please? 2) No, that is a completely different case. Nothing about `object obj` ensures that `obj` is an `Image`, which the later assignment of a `BitmapImage` would clash with.